# I'd like to know if there's any difference in meaning between 'where' and 'the place where' here.

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd like to know if there's any difference in meaning between 'where' and 'the place where' here.

> 1. I'd like to talk about where I usually play basketball
> 2. I'd like to talk about the place that I usually play basketball at.

I think both of them are perefectly the same meaning.

> 3. I like to play basketball where there are a lot of people.
> 4. I like to play basketball at a place where there are a lot of people.

I don't think there's a difference.

Am I right? Or are there any differences?

Answer (score 1):

The only context these might differ is in a more complex sentence, such as one in which "where" might not refer to a physical place. Otherwise, you are correct, these have the exact same meaning, and do in the sentences you have provided.

As a possible example of an exception:

> I wrote an article about playing basketball where I discussed the potential health benefits of the sport.

Note this would have substantially different meaning than:

> I wrote an article about playing basketball at a place where one could remain outside of direct sunlight.

In the first, *where* refers to the article written. In the second, *where* refers to the place one is playing the sport. In the second case, *at a place* helps clarify the meaning.